# Hadoop TeraSort job failed - exited with exitCode: -1000

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run TeraSort benckmark on my hadoop 2.1 cluster. After ran TeraGen successfully, I saw following error when running TeraSort. Could anyone help take a look?

```
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1382326397507_0063 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1382326397507_0063 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1382326397507_0063_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/filecache does not exist.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

More detailed output is as below:

```
[root@hadoop1 hadoop-testsuite]# hadoop jar /root/hadoop/hadoop-2.1.0-beta/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.1.0-beta.jar terasort test_tera test_tera/out
13/12/16 01:18:18 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
13/12/16 01:18:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/12/16 01:18:20 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
Spent 150ms computing base-splits.
Spent 2ms computing TeraScheduler splits.
Computing input splits took 153ms
Sampling 2 splits of 2
Making 1 from 10000 sampled records
Computing parititions took 466ms
Spent 626ms computing partitions.
13/12/16 01:18:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.1.57.195:54313
13/12/16 01:18:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.filesizes is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.filesizes
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.partitioner.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.partitioner.class
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
13/12/16 01:18:21 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
13/12/16 01:18:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1382326397507_0063
13/12/16 01:18:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1382326397507_0063 to ResourceManager at /10.1.57.195:54313
13/12/16 01:18:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop1:54315/proxy/application_1382326397507_0063/
13/12/16 01:18:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1382326397507_0063
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1382326397507_0063 running in uber mode : false
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1382326397507_0063 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1382326397507_0063 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1382326397507_0063_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/filecache does not exist
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
13/12/16 01:18:25 INFO terasort.TeraSort: done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following property defined in yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nm-local-dir</value>
</property>
```